# java jlabel disappears in game loop

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, paintcomponent

The goal here is to use jlabels with an image icon that contains a BufferedImage. Those jlabels can then be easily moved around with the mouse without having to go searching a ton of different BufferedImages on the screen to find out which one is being clicked on.

This is easy to do in a standard JFrame. I've been searching around here for an hour trying to figure out how to implement this in a game loop where a paintComponent is overridden.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        window.setTitle("FX Test");
        window.add(gamePanel);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        gamePanel.startGameThread();

    }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Timer gameLoopTimer;
    public int screenWidthPixels = 640;
    public int screenHeightPixels = 480;
    private int counter;

    private int x = 1;
    private float alpha = 1;
    private final int DELAY = 15;
    private final int INITIAL_DELAY = 200;
    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidthPixels, screenHeightPixels));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocus();
        counter = 0;
        JButton testButton = new JButton("Button Test");
        this.add(testButton);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new String("Label test"));
        label.setVisible(true); // Doesn't seem to be needed.
        this.add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.drawString("Game Panel Testing: " + counter,128,129);

        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        update();
    }

    void startGameThread() {
        gameLoopTimer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
        gameLoopTimer.setInitialDelay(INITIAL_DELAY);
        gameLoopTimer.start();

    }
}
```

That code draws "Game Panel Testing: " and the incrementing counter, but no button and no label.

If I comment out the entire paintComponent I'm overriding, the button and label appear as expected.

What I can't wrap my head around is how to get the label and button to appear again once paintComponent is overridden. I thought the **super.paintComponent(g)** would take care of that automatically, but clearly I'm missing something here. How on earth can I add a bunch of JLabels to this game loop instead of having to manually handle moving of g2 drawn BufferedImages on mouse drag?

Comment: I never disposed the Graphics context within paintComponent. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Another issue could be the size of your GamePanel. Use setMinimumSize() and setPreferredSize() to have reasonable values for the layoutmanager.

Answer (score 0):

The jlabels are not drawn since you have overridden the paintComponent method.
The call to super is on the super class, so you have misunderstood how that call works.
If you put your in a class that inherits from your class with jlabels it will work.

Comment: He overrides paintComponent, not paintChildren or paint. It should be ok.